# Unable to upsertdata in loop

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm pretty new to AmpScript and SF in general so hoping that this is something simple.

I’m getting the following error:

> An error occurred when attempting to execute an UPSERTDATA function
>   call. See inner exception for details. UPSERTDATA Function is not
>   valid in content. This function is only allowed in a non batch
>   context. Function: UPSERTDATA("GPR_EnrolmentAgreement_052017", 1,
>   "EmailAddress", @EmailAddress, "processed", "1")

The UPSERTDATA function is called within a for loop like so

```
for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

 

var @AccountNameOfCDPNumber, @Title, @LastName, @FirstName, @HomeAddress1, @HomeAddress2,@HomeAddress3, @HomePostCode, @HomeCountry, @CompanyName, @CompanyAddress1, @CompanyAddress2, @CompanyAddress3, @CompanyPostCode, @CompanyCountry, @DOB, @DriverLicenceNumber, @DriverLicenceIssueDate, @DriverLicenceExpiryDate, @IssuingAuthority, @MobileTelephone,@EmailAddress, @USA_LDW, @USA_LIS, @USA_PAI_PEC, @CAN_LDW, @CAN_PAI_PEC, @USA_CarPref, @CAN_CarPref, @EMEA_SC, @EMEA_CDW, @EMEA_TP, @EMEA_PAI_PEC, @AUS_MaxCover, @AUS_AER, @NZ_AER, @NZ_PAI_PEC, @NZ_PEC, @EMEA_CarPref, @AUZNZ_CarPref, @GPR_Points, @GPR_FrequentTravellerNumber, @ContactPref, @Signature, @Date, @RentalTerms, @createdAt, @emailOptIn, @postOptIn, @smsOptIn, @TermsAndConditions, @HertzCDPNumber, @ThirdPartyMarketingOptIn, @costCentre

 

Set @row = Row(@rows,@i)

set @AccountNameOfCDPNumber = Field(@row,"AccountNameOfCDPNumber")

set @Title = Field(@row,"Title")

set @costCentre = Field(@row,"costCentre")

set @LastName = Field(@row,"LastName")

set @FirstName = Field(@row,"FirstName")

set @HomeAddress1 = Field(@row,"HomeAddress1")

set @HomeAddress2 = Field(@row,"HomeAddress2")

set @HomeAddress3 = Field(@row,"HomeAddress3")

set @HomePostCode = Field(@row,"HomePostCode")

set @HomeCountry = Field(@row,"HomeCountry")

set @DOB = Field(@row, "DOB")

set @CompanyName = Field(@row,"CompanyName")

set @CompanyAddress1 = Field(@row,"CompanyAddress1")

set @CompanyAddress2 = Field(@row,"CompanyAddress2")

set @CompanyAddress3 = Field(@row,"CompanyAddress3")

set @CompanyPostCode = Field(@row,"CompanyPostCode")

set @CompanyCountry = Field(@row,"CompanyCountry")

set @DriverLicenceNumber = Field(@row,"DriverLicenceNumber")

set @DriverLicenceIssueDate = Field(@row,"DriverLicenceIssueDate")

set @DriverLicenceExpiryDate = Field(@row,"DriverLicenceExpiryDate")

set @IssuingAuthority = Field(@row,"IssuingAuthority")

set @MobileTelephone = Field(@row,"MobileTelephone")

set @EmailAddress = Field(@row,"EmailAddress")

set @USA_LDW = Field(@row,"USA-LDW")

set @USA_LIS = Field(@row,"USA-LIS")

set @USA_PAI_PEC = Field(@row,"USA-PAI_PEC")

set @CAN_LDW = Field(@row,"CAN-LDW")

set @CAN_PAI_PEC = Field(@row,"CAN-PAI_PEC")

set @USA_CarPref = Field(@row,"USA-CarPref")

set @CAN_CarPref = Field(@row,"CAN-CarPref")

set @EMEA_SC = Field(@row,"EMEA-SC")

set @EMEA_CDW = Field(@row,"EMEA-CDW")

set @EMEA_TP = Field(@row,"EMEA-TP")

set @EMEA_PAI_PEC = Field(@row,"EMEA-PAI_PEC")

set @AUS_MaxCover = Field(@row,"AUS-MaxCover")

set @AUS_AER = Field(@row,"AUS-AER")

set @NZ_AER = Field(@row,"NZ-AER")

set @NZ_PAI_PEC = Field(@row,"NZ-PAI_PEC")

set @NZ_PEC = Field(@row,"NZ-PEC")

set @EMEA_CarPref = Field(@row,"EMEA-CarPref")

set @AUZNZ_CarPref = Field(@row,"AUZNZ-CarPref")

set @GPR_Points = Field(@row,"GPR-Points")

set @GPR_FrequentTravellerNumber = Field(@row,"GPR-FrequentTravellerNumber")

set @ContactPref = Field(@row,"ContactPref")

set @Signature = Field(@row,"Signature")

set @Date = Field(@row,"Date")

set @RentalTerms = Field(@row,"RentalTerms")

set @createdAt = Field(@row,"createdAt")

set @emailOptIn = Field(@row,"emailOptIn")

set @postOptIn = Field(@row,"postOptIn")

set @smsOptIn = Field(@row,"smsOptIn")

set @TermsAndConditions = Field(@row,"TermsAndConditions")

set @HertzCDPNumber = Field(@row,"HertzCDPNumber")

set @ThirdPartyMarketingOptIn = Field(@row,"ThirdPartyMarketingOptIn")

]%%

<tr>

<td> %%=v(@HertzCDPNumber)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@AccountNameOfCDPNumber)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@costCentre)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@Title)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@LastName)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@FirstName)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@HomeAddress1)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@HomeAddress2)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@HomeAddress3)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@HomePostCode)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@HomeCountry)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@CompanyName)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@CompanyAddress1)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@CompanyAddress2)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@CompanyAddress3)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@CompanyPostCode)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@CompanyCountry)=%% </td>

<td> %%=FormatDate(@DOB,"MM/dd/yyyy")=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@DriverLicenceNumber)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@DriverLicenceIssueDate)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@DriverLicenceExpiryDate)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@IssuingAuthority)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@MobileTelephone)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@EmailAddress)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@USA_LDW)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@USA_LIS)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@USA_PAI_PEC)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@CAN_LDW)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@CAN_PAI_PEC)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@USA_CarPref)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@CAN_CarPref)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@EMEA_SC)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@EMEA_CDW)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@EMEA_TP)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@EMEA_PAI_PEC)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@AUS_MaxCover)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@AUS_AER)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@NZ_AER)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@NZ_PAI_PEC)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@NZ_PEC)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@EMEA_CarPref)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@AUZNZ_CarPref)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@GPR_Points)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@GPR_FrequentTravellerNumber)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@ContactPref)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@Signature)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@Date)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@RentalTerms)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@createdAt)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@emailOptIn)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@postOptIn)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@smsOptIn)=%% </td>

<td> %%=v(@TermsAndConditions)=%% </td>

</tr>

 

 

%%[

UPSERTDATA("GPR_EnrolmentAgreement_052017", 1, "EmailAddress", @EmailAddress, "processed", "1")

next @i ]%%
```

This code is being called within a scheduled email in Journey Builder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UpsertData is not used in emails. You need to use [UpsertDE()](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/upsertde/). It is a limitation of the function, both are built out identically though so just changing the function should work.